# Getting third cell of each row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, tablerow

```
var Rows = $("#tableid tbody tr");
Rows.each(function(index, element) {
var thirdCell = $(this+":nth-child(3)").text();
    alert(thirdCell);
});
```

Something in the `var thirdCell` line is not working correctly. Each row has four children, all td tags. I want to get the text inside the third cell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like below,

```
var Rows = $("#tableid tbody tr");
Rows.each(function(index, element) {
var thirdCell = $(this).find('td').eq(2).text();
    alert(thirdCell);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`this` is not a string, it's a jquery object, so it can't be appended to when you are building your new selector. You could do it like this:

```
var selector = $(this).selector;
var thirdCell = $(selector+":nth-child(3)").text();
alert(thirdCell);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2URV7/

Answer (score 0):

This will not work because tr has no text. it has TDs. you can apply though html() to get the innerHTML of the tr, or use text() on tds if they actually contain text.

Answer (score 0):

you can get all cells from each row by 0 based index

```
Rows.each(function(index, element) {
    var thirdCell = $(this.cells[2]).text();
    alert(thirdCell);
});
```

or you can get it in original selector

```
var Third = $("#tableid tbody tr > td:nth-child(3)");

Third.each(function(index, element) {
    var thirdCell = $(this).text();
    alert(thirdCell);
});
```